# 404 not found file iframe display in laravel after deploying

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to view a file that I have uploaded in a view but it shows 404 Not Found. It works fine in local but when I deploy it on heroku this error occurs. I tried `php artisan storage:link` but it is not working as well. This is the storage directory for the file:

> `storage/app/public/final_report/2_1_1_1613557659_Ruby Essay.pdf`

My Controller:

```
//get the path for the current Peer Marks final report
$peer_final_report_path = $peer_assignment->final_report['path'];
$peer_final_report_path = "/storage/".$peer_final_report_path;
```

which the $peer_final_report_path will be `/storage/final_report/2_1_1_1613557659_Ruby Essay.pdf`

My View:

```
<!--Display peer marks final report using iframe-->
<div class="card-body" style="float:left;margin-top; 200px;">
    <iframe id="pdf-document" 
    src="{{$peer_final_report_path}}" width="580px" height="800px" >
    This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: Download PDF
    </iframe>
</div>
```

All help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just try something like this.

```
Storage::url($yourfilepath);
```

Comment: I changed my code to ` $peer_final_report_path = $peer_assignment->final_report['path'];
            $peer_final_report_path = Storage::url($peer_final_report_path);` However, It still give the 404 error. And the path was same as `/storage/final_report/2_1_1_1613557659_Ruby `

Comment: Please run command php artisan storage:link and check again.